# Several _document.js for Open Graph markup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying implement og markup to my site (**next.js**).

Main page includes *business.business* type and prefix with

`<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# business: http://ogp.me/ns/business#">`,

but Article's pages in the blog had a *article* type and prefixs

`<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# article: http://ogp.me/ns/article#">`.

Help me to handle the head prefix or is it any possible way to use several **_document.js**?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than multiple `_document.js` files, you can have a single one with dynamic output.

Specifically, you can inspect the `pathname` property of the object passed to the `getInitialProps()` method in your custom `_document.js`, and then from there determine if the page is a the main page or an article.

UPDATE: this doesn't work in Next.js v2.4.5 (the current stable release), but **it does work in v3.0.1-beta.1**.

So, in your case, it might look something like this:

```
// ./pages/_document.js
import Document, { Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'
import flush from 'styled-jsx/server'

const businessPrefix = 'og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# business: http://ogp.me/ns/business#';
const articlePrefix = 'og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# article: http://ogp.me/ns/article#';

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  static getInitialProps ({ pathname, renderPage }) {
    const {html, head, errorHtml, chunks} = renderPage()
    const styles = flush()
    return { pathname, html, head, errorHtml, chunks, styles }
  }

  render () {
    return (
     <html>
       <Head prefix={this.props.pathname === '/' ? businessPrefix : articlePrefix}/>
       <body>
         <Main />
         <NextScript />
       </body>
     </html>
    )
  }
}
```

See a working example at https://next-test-peusycafcq.now.sh/ and https://next-test-peusycafcq.now.sh/article. (Right-click and view-source on each page to see the correct prefix in the `<head>` tag, see https://zeit.co/KYilgchYUEorC1g8s2HO4ALi/next-test/peusycafcq/source to view the complete source code.)

See also https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/3a9c419160c33613cadf3e44b0aba82767c44d3a/readme.md#custom-document and https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/3a9c419160c33613cadf3e44b0aba82767c44d3a/readme.md#fetching-data-and-component-lifecycle

Comment: Are you sure? I tested it out before I posted. I think I was on a beta release, so that might make the difference. Alternatively, you could just use a standard (lowercase) <head> tag. I'm on my phone now, but I'll try and remember to take another look when I get home.

Comment: Yep, sorry, I've amended the answer to mention that this works v3.0.1-beta.1 but not in the current 2.x release.

Comment: Yeah, I tested too

Comment: I went ahead and published my example, you can see the source at https://zeit.co/KYilgchYUEorC1g8s2HO4ALi/next-test/peusycafcq/source and the output at https://next-test-peusycafcq.now.sh/ and https://next-test-peusycafcq.now.sh/article